# Magneto 1.9: checkout strange behavior

Tags: magento-1.9, robots.txt, purchase-order

Very often I observe customers adding to cart then moving to the checkout then disappearing. It looks like a bot or maybe competitors searching for our products and trying to hit us with fake purchases. Google charges us anyway so it cost us money. Very annoying. Any suggestions on what can I do with it or if it is a bot how to make sure and eventually block?

Comment: I would review the web server logs for patterns in the user agent and IP address(s) that will help you make your case that this is illegitimate traffic. Ultimately, it seems like you will need to appeal to Google to remedy this abuse of their system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `robots.txt` and add restriction to bots.

```
User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /

User-agent: baiduspider
Disallow: /

User-agent: AhrefsBot
Disallow: /

User-agent: BLEXBot
Disallow: /

User-Agent: *
```

Check you logs , if you see strange ip accessing your site .

Get in contact with your hosting provider , see what they can help you on this , while getting server logs.

Comment: Added agents to my robots.txt. However it looks like someone is going tough the whole process from selecting page selecting product, add to the basket then go to the checkout entering some data (address, email, phone) then disappearing .... strange.